# Having trouble with Desktop

Tags: chromebook

So I just downloaded Ubuntu through the Chromebook Developer mode but my desktop is bare with not software center or firefox. Could someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

If by desktop you mean the main screen, it's always bare. Open the menu and you should see your software. If that's not what you mean please clarify it a bit...

Comment: I don't have anything besides a search menu and files that are holding how much space I have left on my computer. It says it is my desktop.

Comment: If you've left every thing at it's default, on the left of your screen at the top is a button with the ubuntu logo click that iff you're unsure of that use the following keybaord shortcut Alt + F1 if that doesn't work. You can also try Ctrl + Alt  + T to open a terminal and run the ls command to see all the directories you've got just to verify your install went through correctly..

Comment: So, after some work I found a video to try to explain my situation. Nearly ever person who has a Ubuntu video has one with the whole 9 yards of different web explorers and apps, and all I seem to have is this a desktop like the one in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMyMqqU2Mqs .

Comment: How do I add on things like Chrome, and other things like the Software center?

Comment: Are you asking how to add icons (as in shortcuts) to your desktop??? Because that's the main ubuntu screen that's shown in that video. If so then right click on what ever you want, click create link and drag where you want to put it

Comment: Yes, and I'm asking how I install things to Ubuntu since I'm a new user, I apologize for my lack of knowledge about these things

Comment: I learned the sudo apt get software centre but it says unable to locate package of it. Do I need to update or somenthing?

Comment: The software center comes default you shouldn't have to install it to use it, As for installing things in ubuntu yes you've got two main options sudo apt-get install and using the gui package manager. You should be able to just search "software" in the dash and it should come right up.